# How can I export the color scheme on Material Color Tool for Android

Tags: android, material-design

As you know, Material Team is very kind, because they provide so many tools.

The best one is [Color Tool](https://material.io/color), But When I edit the color scheme on it, I can't find any way to export the style theme file for Android, it's very very sad.

#### Do you know how to export the style theme file for Android on [Color-Tool](https://material.io/color)?

For meet [this scheme](https://material.io/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=EF5350&primary.text.color=ffebee):

[image: abc]

I changed my `colorPrimary`、`colorPrimaryDark`、`colorAccent`、 `Theme parent` and even some I know style-items, **BUT I can't meet it yet**, very bad experience:

[image]

Comment: why don't you create your own style for all elements in res/values/styles? and create your own color resources in res/values/colors ?

Comment: Thanks, I know and absolutely I will do that, but before that, I need to adapt the color scheme I edited on Color Tool first.